# Android Logout timer

Tags: android, android-studio, logout, android-timer

I have made an app. I want to automatically log out from the app after the certain time period when user exit app or app running in the background. I have created timer but it doesn't work as when the app goes in `onStop()` timer also becomes stop. What should I do for this problem?

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: I have developed a a library to take care of this type of use case please feel free to take a look 

https://github.com/jose96043/TimezOut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make all your `Activities` extends one `BaseActivity`. Then in this `BaseActivity` declare pausedMillis paramater :

```
private long pausedMillis;
```

After that Override the `onStop` method :

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    pausedMillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
}
```

In the end Override `onResume` method :

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    try {
        long currentMillis = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        if ( !(this instanceof LoginActivity) && currentMillis - pausedMillis  > 1000 * 60 * 3 ) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, getString(R.string.logout_string), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This will log out you if your app is more then 3 minutes in background. Happy codding :)

Comment: Nice it works for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a service to logout and use AlarmManager with the PendingIntent for that Service to launch after certain time period. Here's an example code:

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent m_intent = new Intent(this, YourService.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 2, m_intent, 0);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + timePeriod, pi);
```

Put logout code in `YourService`.